# How to create a multi-master cluster in Azure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I need to create an Azure Kubernetes Service with 3 master nodes. So far I used to work with single master cluster, now I am in need of creating a multi-master cluster for production environments.

Can I get a way to create an AKS with multiple control planes. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use multi region.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to create a cluster in azure with multiple master nodes. I coudn't find a way to create an AKS with multiple control planes using terraform, also checked in the Azure portal, not able to figure out how to create a cluster with multiple contol planes. Can you help me out to find it

Comment: @Soundarya, try [this](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/terraforming-load-balanced-multi-region-hyperledger-besu-nodes-on-azure-c9c705b72728) or [this](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/multi-region-deployments-with-terraform-kubernetes-a1f51bb96974). Let me know, if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MikołajGłodziak. Sorry, this didn't help me. I have posted the same question in Azure community. They have responded to the query where I am able to understand my issue. Attaching their response for your reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/446862/how-to-create-a-multi-master-cluster-in-azure.html

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Sure @MikołajGłodziak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Soundarya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11691548/soundarya) mentioned in the comment, the solution could be fould [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/446862/how-to-create-a-multi-master-cluster-in-azure.html):

> As your ask is on AKS (Managed service from Azure) with HA enabled Clusters you already have more than one master running. As AKS is a managed offering service you will will not have the visibility/control on this.
> Can I get a way to create an AKS with multiple control planes?
> For this you can check the AKS Uptime SLA, Uptime SLA guarantees 99.95% availability of the Kubernetes API server endpoint for clusters.
> Please check this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/uptime-sla)  for more details.
> If you are using AKS Engine (unmanaged service), then you can specify the number of masters. Please refer to this  [document](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/tree/master/docs)  for more details.